# How to get numbers of rows in sql query?

Tags: c#, datatable, traversal

```
    string query = q;
    SqlCommand queryCommand = new SqlCommand(query, Connection);
    SqlDataReader queryCommandReader = queryCommand.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Load(queryCommandReader);
    List<string> rowText = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn columns in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            rowText.Add(dataTable.Rows[i][columns.ColumnName] + "");
        }
    }
```

in this example I get 4 rows from database the condition in for loop i < 4
I wanna get really numbers of rows not just 4

Answer (score 2):

Use `foreach` for the rows as well
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx

```
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        rowText.Add( row[column] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example simple replace the the `4` by `dataTable.Rows.Count` so that you get:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or switch to `foreach` and use the answer of Gaby.